# Schengen visa overstay

Tags: visa, marriage, overstay

I was issued a shengen visa for 87 days to visit my fiance in hamburg,germany but overstayed by 14 days...upon exit immigration stamped my passport stating that I overstayed but let me go...the visa expired on the 9/08/2019 and I left the shengen area a day before....We would like to get married beginning of October 
.when can I apply for a visa again to go back and what are the implications....any advice is appreciated much...

Comment: Are you planning to live permanently in Germany after your marriage, or do you want to get married as a visitor?

Comment: I plan to live permanently with my fiance after we are married...we already started the process to get married in Denmark but they are awaiting the visa to proceed

Comment: If you’re asking when you can apply again to go back as a visitor, having previously overstayed and with a marriage/settlement visa already underway, I would say possibly best to proceed with caution. The authorities might consider that you may abuse a visitor visa, therefore it might be best to await the decision on the marriage visa rather than try to return as a visitor meanwhile.